# French highway terms?

Tags: vocabulaire, transports

Is *sortie* correct for referring to an exit from a highway, and is *entrée* correct for the entrance?

Also, how would you say the "exit ramp" or "entrance ramp"? *La rampe de sortie et la rampe d'entrée* ?

Lastly, is *grande route* the correct term for highways?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A "highway" is usually known as an "autoroute". "Sortie" is the correct term, and "Entrance" is "accès", but it is rare to see it in use outside technical stuff. "Highway ramps" are known as "bretelles" (either "bretelle d'accès" or "bretelle de sortie").

To add in a related term, an "interchange" is known as an "échangeur".

Comment: So what *do* you call an entrance in casual talk? And I actually have no idea what an interchange is. Not a word used in the U.S. very often, if at all.

Comment: [Interchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchange_%28road%29) (I'm probably biased because the woird has been in the news a lot here due to a divisive reconstruction project). I don't think I've ever heard someone needing to use the term for an entrance ramp, they just say "prendre" or (in Quebec) "embarquer sur l'autoroute". People need to explicitly refer to exit points all the time, but *hardly ever* to access ones!

Comment: @Circeus: I do use *entrée* et *sortie*.

Answer (score 6):

> Is "sortie" correct for referring to an exit from a highway, and is
>   "entree" correct for the entrance?

*Sortie* and *entrée* are both correct. *accès* may be used instead of *entrée*.

> Also, how would you say the "exit ramp" or "entrance ramp"? La rampe
>   de sortie et la rampe d'entree?

*Rampe de sortie* is correct, *rampe d'accès* might be used (instead of <strike>*rampe d'entrée*</strike>). Technical terms are *voie d'insertion* (or *voie d'accélération*) and *voie de décélération*.

> Lastly, is "grande route" the correct term for highways?

An "highway" may be translated as *autoroute* and sometime as *voie express*.

The French traffic code refers to both as *route à chaussée séparée* (divided highway) and to *route pour automobile* (casually *autoroute*) and *voie rapide* ou *voie express* (casually *voie express*). Difference between *autoroute* and *voie express* 
are technical and safety level.

Urban highway are usually know as *rocade* or *périphérique* (the former only apply for ring road).